# Retrieving records from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Just looking for better solution.I'm retrieving all the records from mysql. Then I will send this data by email. Its working fine. Is there any better solution? thanks

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE order_id = '".$data['order_id']."'";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $message_admin .= "<table  style='text-align:center;' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='7'> 
        <tr>
            <td>Source</td>
            <td>".$data['source']."</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>".$data['email']."</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message</td>
            <td>".$data['message']."</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
    }
```

Comment: Better in what way? And you want to post the entire code, including SQL query.

Comment: Why, what's wrong with this one?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "better"

Comment: I think this type of question is better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would benefit from: http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Instead of the complicated string manipulation you are doing now.

You are setting $row, but using $data?

Comment: When I print this variable. `echo $message_admin`. It displayed the data. I'm passing this variable to mail. And I'm getting empty message. What wrong with this code? Thanks for pointing me error `$row`.

Comment: Mail function `$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
      mail($to_client, $subject_client, $message_admin, $headers);`

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. Try sending a simple test message with php first, then put in the code you wrote.

Comment: Simple test message delivered successfully.

Comment: OK, now keep making changes one at a time till you find the change that causes a blank message.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the following to improve your code.

[mysql-real-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

[SELECT * vs SELECT column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180375/select-vs-select-column)