# Querying different table based on a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that I would like to query either the production or the "work in progress" table, based on the parameter I am passing in. I could write two separate stored procedures, but I thought this was worth a try.

something along the lines of:

```
create procedure getUserDetails
    @userID int,
    @prod varchar(5)
as 
    begin
        select * from
            if (@prod = 'true')
            Begin
                userprod_table
            else
                userwip_table
            end 
    where something = 'something'
END
```

Is this at all possible? I wouldn't want to write 2 SP that are almost identical :-/

Comment: Not really related, but [Using SELECT * in production Code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180435/1048425) is **NEVER** a good idea. Do your two tables have the same columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a simple `if(@prod = 'true')` statement like below:

```
if (@prod = 'true')
begin
    select * from userprod_table where something = 'something'
end  else
begin
    select * from userwip_table where something = 'something'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE so that your main query isn't repeated

```
with usertable as
(
    select * from userprod_table where 1 = @flag
    union
    select * from userwip_table where 0 = @flag
)
select ... from usertable ...
```