# SQL Server equivalent to Using for a JOIN to avoid duplicate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm looking for a way to join relational tables on a PK similar to MySQL "using" so that I can eliminate duplicate columns.

Here is an example:

```
select * 
from MovieHasDirector
join Director on MovieHasDirector.directorID = Director.directorID
where Director.name
like '%Steven Spiel%'
```

Returns:

```
3818    976 976 Steven Spielberg
3962    976 976 Steven Spielberg
4317    976 976 Steven Spielberg
4715    976 976 Steven Spielberg
```

When what I really want is:

```
3818    976 Steven Spielberg
3962    976 Steven Spielberg
4317    976 Steven Spielberg
4715    976 Steven Spielberg
```

You can see the duplicate directorID column is gone.  In MySQL you can do this with the using(directorID) instead of the ON directorID = directorID

Of course I am trying to do this without having to manually specify the Select MovieHasDirector.movieID, Director.*   I want the returned records to overlap the columns that are the same.  How can I do this?

Comment: So MySQL makes it easier to use `select *` in production code, while SQL Server makes it harder, [which is a good thing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180435/11683).

Comment: I had [the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481055/alternatives-to-using-in-a-join-for-sql-server-for-avoiding-duplicated-columns-i). You might want to take a look to [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32482404/2436175).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that in SQL Server, you have to specify column names that you want to return:

```
select MovieHasDirector.column1, MovieHasDirector.column2, Director.column1
from MovieHasDirector
join Director on MovieHasDirector.directorID = Director.directorID
where Director.name
like '%Steven Spiel%'
```

You can use table aliases to make it a bit easier:

```
select M.column1, M.column2, D.column1
from MovieHasDirector M
join Director D on M.directorID = D.directorID
where D.name
like '%Steven Spiel%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way will be to manually select the columns you need.

```
select a.ID, a.directorID, b.name from MovieHasDirector a, Director b
where a.directorID = b.directorID
```