# Alternatives to USING in a JOIN for SQL Server for avoiding duplicated columns in joined table

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

SQL Server [does not offer the keyword `USING` in the context of a `JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479936/sql-join-using-using-column-name-is-not-a-recognized-table-hints-option),
[nor it provides a `NATURAL JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826613/natural-join-in-sql-server).

Besides explicitly (manually) listing all the columns ([link to otherwise duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350817/sql-server-equivalent-to-using-for-a-join-to-avoid-duplicate-columns)), is there an alternative to obtain a table in which the columns I am joining onto, which have the same name in the 2 joined tables, are not duplicated?

As an intermediate step, I have tried to save in a temporary table the result

```
SELECT INTO #MyTempTable * FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN tableB 
ON tableA.commonColumn = tableB.commonColumn;
```

But I already get an error:

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'commonColumn' in table '#MyTempTable' is specified more than once.

Comment: if you use `select * from ...` then you have to make sure column name should be unique

Comment: Assuming you join two tables, both of which have a "Name" column, in what form would you want the resulting column set? (Rename one of the "Names", keep only one, or what?)

Comment: @PhilipKelley keep only one.

Comment: `Select A.*, B.ColsnotInA, B.Cols2NotInA...`  or vice versa pick the table with fewer columns to type out.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks, this is already one step forward!

Comment: Re: Name column, if only one, then which one? Say, "Person.Name" vs. "Store.Name"? (It's slightly simpler if they are the columns you joined on, but only slightly.)

Comment: @PhilipKelley They are exactly identical (title and content) in the join result, so it doesn't matter

Comment: I +1ed @X.L.Ant's answer. @ BlackJacketMack's idea could work, but unless you've got dozens of similar queries like this, it is almost certainly more effort than it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not easy. But it is possible. Developing from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628588/2436175), you would first create two separated lists with all the columns of the 2 tables, excluding the common column on which you want to join:

```
DECLARE @columnsA varchar(8000)

SELECT @columnsA = ISNULL(@columnsA + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(column_name)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableA' AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'commonColumn'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

DECLARE @columnsB varchar(8000)

SELECT @columnsB = ISNULL(@columnsB + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(column_name)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableB' AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'commonColumn'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Then  you would use them for your query, selecting the commonColumn only for one of the table:

```
EXEC ('SELECT tableA.commonColumn, ' + @columnA + ', ' + @columnsB + ' FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.commonColumn = tableB.commonColumn;')
```

So there's at least one way to do it. :) It is apparently also moderately efficient. I am not an SQL expert, but I suppose there is a way to create a function out of this, maybe one function to "select all columns but [...]" and one function that would do the join as `USING` would do.

---

It becomes a little bit simpler if in listing we add also the containing table. In this way we need to extract only the column names from one table.

```
DECLARE @columnsB varchar(8000)

SELECT @columnsB = ISNULL(@columnsB + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(table_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(column_name)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableB' AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'commonColumn'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

And the query is modified into:

```
EXEC ('SELECT tableA.* ', ' + @columnsB + ' FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.commonColumn = tableB.commonColumn;')
```

Comment: That's the only way. On top of that. I'd probably go for `WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('tableA', 'tableB' AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'commonColumn'` with picking `DISTINCT column_name`. There might be names with the same name there, can't there? And only then form columns list.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Apart from the "joining" columns, I am keeping off from having common column names into different tables. I lost a lot of time today checking if I could add a `originatingTable.` prefix to the columns of my joined table.

Answer (score 4):

No there is not.   The only way to avoid this error in a `SELECT INTO` query is to write out your column list after `SELECT`, instead of `SELECT *`.

Comment: I believe there must be a way, even if it was a complicated one.

Comment: Well you could replace your tables with views or derived tables that replace common column names with different names, but at some point or other in that chain of code, you are specifying column names.   There's no way around that.

Comment: Like I said, at some point in the code stack, you're specifying column names, even if you create the list programmatically.   But you can't do it with a `SELECT *` query.

Comment: If the listing is done automatically, my problem is solved.

Comment: If that is true, then you asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 2):

The only alternative is to avoid `SELECT`ing `*`:

TableA

```
foo | bar
---------
```

TableB

```
foo | baz
---------
```

When selecting * from both tables, you'll end up with 2 columns named `foo`, which is not allowed in a single table.

Name the selected columns using unique names, and this will work.

```
SELECT INTO #TableTemp t1.foo foo1, t1.bar, t2.foo foo2, t2.baz
FROM tableA t1
INNER JOIN tableB t2 ON t1.foo = t2.foo
```

But while you're at it, no need to insert the common column twice (as `t1.foo = t2.foo`). Select just one of them:

```
SELECT INTO #TableTemp t1.foo, t1.bar, t2.baz
FROM tableA t1
INNER JOIN tableB t2 ON t1.foo = t2.foo
```

EDIT: As stated by Philip Kelley, this problem only occurs when you try to save the resultset into a table. As long as you only select data, everything works fine with duplicate column names.

Comment: A fussy point: the result set generated by a query *can* contain duplicated column names. The duplicated name problem only kicks in when you try to save this as a table via the `into` clause.

Comment: @PhilipKelley Of course. I selected so many duplicate columns in my life that I forgot to mention this point :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend this, but in an effort to answer your question, you could create a sql clause builder function that automatically creates column aliases for your individual tables prefixed with the tablename (or customize it if you'd like):

```
declare @tableName nvarchar(100);


set @tableName = 'TestTable';

select @tableName + '.' + c.name + ' AS ' + @tableName + '_' + c.name
from sys.tables t
    inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
where
    t.name = @tableName
```

**Output for my little 2-column table**

```
TestTable.TestColumn1 AS TestTable_TestColumn1
TestTable.TestColumn2 AS TestTable_TestColumn2
```

**Hypothetical usage**

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000) = '';
set @sql = myClauseBuilder('TestTable');

set @sql = @sql + ',' + myClauseBuilder('TestTable2');

set @sql = @sql + ' FROM TestTable INNER JOIN TestTable2....(etc.)

exec @sql
```