# laravel performance difference just get vs select and get

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a project(Laravel 5.4) where i need to improve performance as much as i can.
So i was wondering what is the performance difference between:

```
$model->get()
```

get method takes all variables('created_at','updated_at', etc), so the select should be faster.

```
$model->select('many variables to select')->get();
```

select method is an additional query, so it takes more time, so maybe just get is faster?

I wanted to know if select and get is better in all occasions or are there any moments where just get is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences between `Model::get()` and `Model::select(['f1', 'f2'])->get()` is only at the query

```
// Model::get()
SELECT * FROM table

// Model::select(['f1', 'f2'])->get()
SELECT f1, f2 FROM table
```

Both runs database query ONCE, and prepare the collection of model instances to you. `select` simply construct eloquent to only select fields you need. Performance gain is almost negligible or can be worse. Read about it here: [Is it bad for performance to select all columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093187/is-it-bad-for-performance-to-select-all-columns)