# sp_executesql select * is much faster than select column fields?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005, sp-executesql

I encounter an issue where when I use `sp_executesql`  to `select *` (6 seconds) is much faster than `select column` fields (2min).  (using sql server 2005)

I can't understand why the performance is so much different as I thought select by column field suppose to be faster. (or it shouldn't be so much different..)

anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure that's the only difference? Can you get some query execution plans? Maybe a weird cached query plan from back when the table sizes have been much different? Can you restart the database server and try again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [select \* vs select column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180375/select-vs-select-column)