# Is it faster to only query specific columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select

I've heard that it is faster to select colums manually ("col1, col2, col3, etc") instead of querying them all with "*".

But what if I don't even want to query all columns of a table? Would it be faster to query, for Example, only "col1, col2" insteaf of "col1, col2, col3, col4"?

From my understanding SQL has to search through all of the columns anyway, and just the return-result changes. I'd like to know if I can achieve a gain in performance by only choosing the right columns.

(I'm doing this anyway, but a backend API of one of my applications returns more often than not all columns, so I'm thinking about letting the user manually select the columns he want)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, reducing the number of columns in the `select` is a minor optimization.  It means that less data is being returned from the database server to the application calling the server.  Less data is usually faster.

Under most circumstances, this a minor improvement.  There are some cases where the improvement can be more important:

- If a covering index is available for the query, so the index satisfies the query without having to access data pages.
- If some fields are very long, so records occupy multiple pages.
- If the volume of data being retrieved is a small fraction (think < 10%) of the overall data in each record.

Listing the columns individually is a good idea, because it protects code from changes in underlying schema.  For instance, if the name of a column is changed, then a query that lists columns explicitly will break with an easy-to-understand error.  This is better than a query that runs and produces erroneous results.

Comment: good detailed answer. My query retrieves large binary (images), so listing other columns when I don't need images will be a better idea, yes?

Answer (score 2):

You should try not to use `select *`.

- **Inefficiency in moving data to the consumer.**  When you SELECT *, you're often retrieving more columns from the database than your application really needs to function.  This causes more data to move from the database server to the client, slowing access and increasing load on your machines, as well as taking more time to travel across the network.  This is especially true when someone adds new columns to underlying tables that didn't exist and weren't needed when the original consumers coded their data access.
- **Indexing issues.**  Consider a scenario where you want to tune a query to a high level of performance.  If you were to use *, and it returned more columns than you actually needed, the server would often have to perform more expensive methods to retrieve your data than it otherwise might.  For example, you wouldn't be able to create an index which simply covered the columns in your SELECT list, and even if you did (including all columns [*shudder*]), the next guy who came around and added a column to the underlying table would cause the optimizer to ignore your optimized covering index, and you'd likely find that the performance of your query would drop substantially for no readily apparent reason.
- **Binding Problems.** When you SELECT *, it's possible to retrieve two columns of the same name from two different tables.  This can often crash your data consumer.  Imagine a query that joins two tables, both of which contain a column called "ID".  How would a consumer know which was which?  SELECT * can also confuse views (at least in some versions SQL Server) when underlying table structures change -- [the view is not rebuilt, and the data which comes back can be nonsense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful/3639964#3639964).  And the worst part of it is that you can take care to name your columns whatever you want, but the next guy who comes along might have no way of knowing that he has to worry about adding a column which will collide with your already-developed names.

I got this from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful/3639964#3639964) answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this topic has already been covered here:

[select * vs select column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180375/select-vs-select-column)

I believe it covers your concerns as well.  Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

All the column labels and values occupy some space. Sending them to the issuer of the request instead of a subset of the columns means sending more data. More data is sent slower.

If you have columns, like
`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `bio`, `url`

and you want to get only the `username` and `password`, then

```
select username, password ...
```

is quicker than

```
select * ...
```

because `id`, `email`, `bio` and `url` are sent as well for the latter, which makes the response larger. But the main problem with `select *` is different. It might be the source of inconsistencies if, for some reason the order of the columns changed. Also, it might retrieve data you do not want to retrieve. It is always better to have a whitelist with the columns you actually want to retrieve.