# what is Difference between select * from table and Select name,mobile from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Table has only 2 Columns

```
`Select * from table` ----Execution time 10 second
Select name,mobile from table--Execution time 5 second
```

Comment: Cached table data? (Try the opposite order.)

Comment: check out this post in this same forum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180375/select-vs-select-column

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180375/select-vs-select-column

Answer (score 0):

`Select *` and `Select Columns` doesn't have any differences ***when you are scanning the whole table***..

Below differences can crop up when you use unnecessary columns

1.Scan of whole another table due to Rowlookup cost exceeding limit
2.Sending data over network

In your case the difference can be due to locking,blocking,memory pressure...whole lot of reasons..but not due to expanding all columns vs *

Excerpt from Conor cunningham on the same..

Comment: That's the opposite of what is being seen though, he has only the two columns.

Comment: I clarified that in differences section

Answer (score 0):

Did you do 'select *', then 'select name, mobile' right after ?
If yes, then it's warm caching. Your data is in memory. 
The second query runs faster.