# How to select all columns while trimming the result of one of them?

Tags: sql, oracle, case, trim

I have a table

This query will select all columns as they are.

```
select * from t1
```

But I need to trim one of those columns.

Can I do it this way?

```
select * 
  case 
    when column4 is not null
      then substr(column4, - 5)
from table
```

Or do I need

```
select * 
  case 
    when column4 is not null
      then column4 = substr(column4, - 5)
from table
```

The result should have all columns exept column4 unchanged.

Comment: Don't be lazy, specify them all! (But you can skip the case, simply do just the substring part.)

Comment: @jar there are more than 20 columns in a table and more than 10 tables. I will need to specify 200 columns at the very least. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: It can be a bit of a pain but always prefer a column list, [select * vs select column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180375/select-vs-select-column)

Answer (score 0):

There's no operator for "all columns except something", unfortunately. You'd  have to specify all of them:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, SUBSTRING(column4, LENGTH(column4) - 5), etc
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax should be like this:

```
select column1,
       column2,
       column3,
       case 
       when column4 is not null 
        then substring(column4, length(column4) - 5)
       end column4 ,
       column5
  from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what you want to accomplish. This works:

```
select substr(column4, 0, 5), t1.* from sometable t1;
```

However, it returns column4 twice. Once with 5 characters (use length as in the other answers if you want to discard the last 5 rather than using a fixed length, not clear what your goal is) and once with all characters.

You could also generate the SQL with PL/SQL using user_tab_columns. If you just want to save yourself some typing something like this might work:

```
declare
  v_sql varchar2(1024) := null;
begin
  for rec in (select column_name, table_name from user_tab_columns
    where table_name = 'TEST1') loop
    if v_sql is null then
      v_sql := 'select ';
    else
      v_sql := v_sql || ',';
    end if;   
    if rec.column_name = 'C2' then
      v_sql := v_sql || ' substr(' || rec.table_name || '.c2, 0, 5)';
    else
      v_sql := v_sql || rec.table_name || '.' || rec.column_name;
    end if;
  end loop;
  v_sql := v_sql || ' from test1';
  dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
end;
/
```

No points for code style, but it works and prints the SQL. Add more special cases if you need to truncate multiple columns and add the other tables as needed.