# MySQL - Special characters in column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, special-characters

I got a big data (approximately 600,000).

I want the rows with value "word's" will appear.

Special characters will be completely ignored.

TABLE:

```
| column_value  |
| ------------- |
| word's        |
| hello         |
| world         |
```

QUERY: `select * from table where column_value like '%words%'`

RESULTS:

```
| column_value  |
| ------------- |
| word's        |
```

I want the rows with special characters will appear and ignore their special characters.

Can you please help me how can we achieve it with fast runtime?

Comment: Have you tried like with '%word\'s%' ?

Comment: You could replace the * selector by only columns you want to select. Your query would probably run faster.

Comment: @skelwa  i should assume that the search keyword is "words" not word's. I am after the value of the column.

Comment: The starting % in your LIKE clause causes the index for this column to not to be used. If you only want words starting with some string, try removing starting '%' or else have a look at MySQL full text index.

Comment: @Jojoes what do you mean? 'select column_value  from .....'. This doesn't matter. I think the work is on the sql filters inside Where clause

Comment: @Mefenamic as you want ... but more content about the topic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180375/select-vs-select-column) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Comment: @Jojoes i don't know if you get my inquiry correctly. Please reread. i got no problem with selecting all rows. my problem is filtering returned data with special characters.

Comment: @Mefenamic you said you wanted fast runtime, so I proposed a possible optimization. It doesn't relate to the filter, that's why I wrote a comment.

Comment: Add these to your example and show which ones to return:  `words`, `x-word`, `word-smith`, `foo-bar`.  (The statement of the problem is still unclear.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace to remove the "special" character prior the matching.

```
SELECT *
       FROM table
       WHERE replace(column_value, '''', '') LIKE '%words%';
```

Nest the `replace()` calls for other characters.

Or you try it with regular expressions.

```
SELECT *
       FROM table
       WHERE column_value REGEXP 'w[^a-zA-Z]*o[^a-zA-Z]*r[^a-zA-Z]*d[^a-zA-Z]*s';
```

`[^a-zA-Z]*` matches optional characters, that are not a, ..., y and z and not A, ..., Y and Z, so this matches your search word also with any non alphas between the letters.

Or you have a look at the options [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) brings with it. Maybe that can help too.

Comment: thanks for this @sticky-bit. this helps much. I would rather use the replace but kinda long for all characters. Furthermore, how can we do it in full-text search? can't use the replace inside match(replace()).

Answer (score 0):

You must add an index on your column_value.
[MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html)