# How to start column value with specific characters followed by auto increasing value in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

There is one column or field named 'Software Code' that should be started with FREE with 5 numeric value. for example: FREE00001,FREE00002,....FREE00029,....FREE0015, and so on. what query to be run to get desired output.[example of format of Software Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNdZq.png)

Need detailed query code for above result

Comment: If the only prefix is FREE why bother?

Comment: Just use a computed column that concatenates them together. Or to be honest just concatenate it when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/views.html).
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE softwares (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO softwares VALUES
  (DEFAULT),
  (DEFAULT),
  (DEFAULT);

SELECT * FROM softwares;
```

Result:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SwCodes AS
  SELECT
    *, -- FYI, using an asterisk here is a bad habit.
       -- For more https://stackoverflow.com/q/3180375/3350428 
    CONCAT('FREE', LPAD(id, 5, '0')) AS `Software Code`
  FROM softwares;

SELECT * FROM SwCodes;
```

FYI, using an asterisk here is a bad habit. For more [select * vs select column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3180375/3350428).
Result:

```
+----+---------------+
| id | Software Code |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | FREE00001     |
|  2 | FREE00002     |
|  3 | FREE00003     |
+----+---------------+
```

Try it on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OKSnc1en).