# PHP videos multiple pages doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, video

I'm working on a simple vlog site project and I'm trying to show only 20 video thumbnail per page and I've wrote this code in the index to divide the videos to multiple pages and then pagination them ... the problem is that it shows the same first video's thumbnail 20 times per page for infinity pages.

I really need help with this code

```
<?php

   require_once ('db.php') ;
   require_once ('VideosApi.php') ;
   $count = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(id) AS numb FROM videos ORDER BY id');  
   $array = mysql_fetch_assoc($count);
   $number = $array['numb'];  
   mysql_free_result($count);  
   $PerPage = 20;
   $nbPage = ceil(abs($number/$PerPage));
   if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 0 && $_GET['page'] <= $nbPage && preg_match('#^[0-9]+$#',$_GET['page'])){ $cPage = $_GET['page']; }
   else{ $cPage = 1; }  

   $Query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Videos ORDER BY id LIMIT '.(($cPage-1) * $PerPage).','.$PerPage);  

              $videos = Videos_Get() ;
           if ($videos == Null)
             die ('problem');

        $vcount = @count ($videos) ;

           if ($vcount == 0)
             die('no videos') ;



        For ($i = 0; $i < $vcount; $i++)
          {
        $video = $videos [$i];

        if ($video->time > 3600)
            $duration = gmdate("H:i:s",$video->time);
        else
            $duration = gmdate("i:s",$video->time);




        while($Rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($Query)){ 

          echo ( "<div class=\"video\">
                <a href=\"video.php?id=$video->id\"><img src=\"$video->img\"></a><span class=\"class-video-name\">$video->name</span>
                <div class=\"class-video-footer\">
                <span class=\"class-video-duration\">$duration</span>
                </div>
         </div>") ; }   

        } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few tips before we get to the answer proper:

1. Don't use `mysql_*`. That family of functions is now deprecated and support will be dropped in future versions of PHP. For code longevity, consider using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
2. Use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to check if a string has a numeric value. Using `preg_match()` is very load heavy for such a simple task.
3. Try to avoid using `SELECT *` inside of MySQL queries. Very rarely do you need *everything* from the table so fetching all fields for rows is [very inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960036/best-to-use-when-calling-a-lot-of-fields-in-mysql/1960043#1960043) (especially if you're not using indexes optimally).

That having been said, I've taken some time to rewrite your code following the practices I've preached above. Below is the modified code, and underneath that an explanation of what was wrong:

---

**Update `db.php` as follows:**

```
<?php

$db = new PDO( 'mysql:dbname=DATABASE_NAME;host=127.0.0.1', 'DATABASE_USER', 'DATABASE_PASSWORD' );

?>
```

Now for your main file:

```
<?php

require_once 'db.php';
require_once 'VideosApi.php';

$count = $db->query( 'SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM videos' )->fetchObject();
$number = $count->total;

$perPage = 20;
$pages   = ceil( $number / $perPage );

$page    = ( isset($_GET['page']) ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$page    = ( $page < 1 || $page > $pages || !is_numeric($page) ) ? 1 : $page;

$offset  = ($page - 1) * $perPage;
$query   = $db->query( 'SELECT id, img, name, time FROM videos ORDER BY id LIMIT '.$offset.','.$perPage );

if( $query->rowCount() < 1 )
{
    die( 'No videos' );
}

$html = '';

while( $video = $query->fetchObject() )
{
    $duration = ($video->time > 3600) ? gmdate('H:i:s', $video->time) : gmdate('i:s', $video->time);

    $html.= '<div class="video">';
    $html.= "\n\t".'<a href=\"video.php?id='.$video->id.'">';
    $html.= "\n\t\t".'<img src="'.$video->img.'" />';
    $html.= "\n\t".'</a>';
    $html.= "\n\t".'<span class="class-video-name">'.$video->name.'</span>';
    $html.= "\n\t".'<div class="class-video-footer">';
    $html.= "\n\t\t".'<span class="class-video-duration">'.$duration.'</span>';
    $html.= "\n\t".'</div>';
    $html.= "\n".'</div>';
}

echo $html;

?>
```

The problem with your original code is a little hard to determine since you do not provide the contents of `VideosApi.php`, which is where I assume you define `Videos_Get()`. Anyway, what I suspect is happening, is that `Videos_Get()` is actually ignoring all of your pagination, but as I say, it's difficult to diagnose because we can't see all of your code!

Comment: Your code is great .. it works well and also looks very professional

I hope one day I can code just like you .. thanks a lot :D

Comment: If the code above helped, please consider upvoting and accepting it as the correct answer.