# Creating MYSQL VIEW with SELECT *

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view, wildcard

In MYSQL for creating VIEWs

If I write the `SELECT * FROM ... as a VIEW` will the view store it forever as * or will it actually choose the current columns and store the query as that (as in instead of storing `SELECT *` it will store `SELECT foo,bar,biz` etc.)

I have read multiple times that using `SELECT * FROM ...` is bad practice for various reasons including those mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960036/best-to-use-when-calling-a-lot-of-fields-in-mysql/1960043#1960043). So i do wish to avoid those problems.

Answer (score 2):

Creating stored views in MySQL can be fraught with unintended performance consequences. Consider carefully whether creating a stored view is an appropriate solution to the problem. Or whether creating a view is potentially creating a problem that is larger than the problem it was implemented to solve.

---

The question you asked could be answered with a simple test case, assuming table `test.foo` exists...

```
 USE test ; 

 CREATE VIEW voo AS SELECT * FROM foo ;

 SHOW CREATE VIEW voo ; 

 DROP VIEW voo ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response I was not aware that there is such a thing as view that is not stored, and this may make me rewrite my question. Is a stored view different than a simply creating a view in phpmyadmin for example?

Comment: A *stored* view as opposed to an *inline* view. In the MySQL parlance, an inline view is referred to as a "derived table", e.g. **`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM foo) voo`.**  The bit between the parens there is an "inline view", assigned an alias "voo".  We could create a *stored* view definition (as the example in the answer), and then `SELECT * FROM voo` to the same net effect (and performance issues). The difference is that in one, the definition of `voo` exists *inline* in the query, and is only available in that context. A *stored* view is available in other contexts.